# GET Request return 400 bad response

Tags: c#, http, get, httpclient, bad-request

It's a generic question, but I need help with my specific case.

I have a simple GET endpoint (see image) which I've tested with Postman and it works

It takes two id tokens in the header and thats it.

I've put breakpoints in the code and copied the exact instance of the ids into Postman and the request works, but executing from code, I get a 400 response

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("https://*******.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/uploads/image.jpg"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,                       
                };                    
                var idToken = Application.Current.Properties["id_token"].ToString();
                var accessToken = Application.Current.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Add("Id-Token", idToken);
                request.Headers.Add("Access-Token", accessToken);

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                
            }
```

I've tried with and without the content-type header and makes no difference. Also doesn't matter if it's present in Postman

This is a Xamarin project which is where Application.Current.Properties comes from. I'm utilising other endpoints in the application are there are no issues with accessing the tokens like this.

[image]

Comment: I suspect you have the wrong URL.

Comment: @John I wondered that but if I paste what's in the code into Postman it works

Comment: 400 Bad Request
    The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: @Ryn9011 Did you checked the response's body? It could indicate why the request is treated as "bad".

Comment: The response body complains that a valid access token is required.. Am I not adding multiple headers in the correct way?